starting a cmd window that runs multiple actions
i want to start a cmd window with the "start" command in a .bat file that runs multiple commands without user input. for example i want to open a cmd window using BATCH that runs the following commands:
tree
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
stop

is this even possible, if not, is there another way to stop cmd windows when they finish running a command?
i tried using newline replacements but none worked. i also coulnd find anything about this topic online.

Do you need to keep the window open after all of the commands are complete? Batch scripts inherently open windows when they run.

Have you opened a Command Prompt window, typed cmd /?, and pressed the [ENTER] key? What about tree /?, timeout /?, stop /?, (or when that fails, exit /?). Have you performed any research at all to find out how it may be possible to run a series of commands in cmd.exe. There are certainly hundreds of examples on this site which show how this may be done with the use of a separating character. Please try a little harder to solve your problem before expecting it to be spoon fed to you.
